# GmailApp.sendEmail() Add reply to address

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have this code from my google script app the code sends an email to a recipient every time a user submits the form.

```
function LeadNotifier(e) {

 var values = e.values;
  var htmlBody = '<div background:#E5E8E8;><h2 style="color:#154360;">MENSAJE WEB E.LUCIANA<h2><ul>';
  for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {

    var data = values[i];
    htmlBody += '<li>' + ": " + data + '</li>';
  };
  htmlBody += '</ul><h3 ><strong style="color:green;" >Web Site:</strong> Edificio Luciana</h3></div>';
  GmailApp.sendEmail('ventas@edificioluciana.com','Cotización de Departamento','',       {htmlBody:htmlBody});
   GmailApp.sendEmail("starjuster@gmail.com","gomez_isaac@outlook.com","TPS report status",{htmlBody:htmlBody});

}
```

But now my client wants to add the user's email as a reply-to so they don't have to fill that field when they respond to customers.

is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options), you can set the `replyTo` field in the options.

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("recipient@example.com", "Subject", "Body", {
  htmlBody: htmlBody,
  replyTo: "replyto@example.com"
});
```

Comment: I couldn't find that documentation not even to save my life, thanks a lot man